# How to add class to body tag on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

Hi I have created 3 modals for wordpress for login registration and password reset but I have a problem with the slide menu z-index so would be great to find a way to add a class to body tag when I click to the modal button.

this is my javascript code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(a) {
    a("#pop_login, #pop_signup").on("click", function(b) {
        return formToFadeOut = a("#register"), formtoFadeIn = a("#login"), "pop_signup" == a(this).attr("id") && (formToFadeOut = a("#login"), formtoFadeIn = a("#register")), formToFadeOut.fadeOut(10, function() {
            formtoFadeIn.fadeIn()
        }), !1
    }), a("#pop_forgot").click(function() {
        return formToFadeOut = a("#login"), formtoFadeIn = a("#forgot_password"), formToFadeOut.fadeOut(10, function() {
            formtoFadeIn.fadeIn()
        }), !1
    }), a(document).on("click", ".modal-backdrop, span.close", function() {
        return a("#login, #register, #forgot_password").fadeOut(10, function() {
            a(".login_overlay").remove()
        }), !1
    }), a("#show_login, #show_signup").on("click", function(b) {
        a("body").prepend('<div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 541px;"></div>'), "show_login" == a(this).attr("id") ? a("#login").fadeIn(10) : a("#register").fadeIn(10), b.preventDefault()
    }), a("#login_form, #registration_form").on("submit", function(b) {
        return !!a(this).valid() && (a("p.errors", this).show().text(ajax_auth_object.loadingmessage), action = "ajaxlogin", username = a("#login_form #username").val(), password = a("#login_form #password").val(), email = "", security = a("#login_form #security").val(), "registration_form" == a(this).attr("id") && (action = "ajaxregister", username = a("#signonname").val(), password = a("#signonpassword").val(), email = a("#email").val(), security = a("#signonsecurity").val()), ctrl = a(this), a.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: ajax_auth_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: action,
                username: username,
                password: password,
                email: email,
                security: security
            },
            success: function(b) {
                a("p.errors", ctrl).text(b.message), 1 == b.loggedin && (document.location.href = ajax_auth_object.redirecturl)
            }
        }), void b.preventDefault())
    }), a("#forgot_pass").on("submit", function(b) {
        return !!a(this).valid() && (a("p.errors", this).show().text(ajax_auth_object.loadingmessage), ctrl = a(this), a.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: ajax_auth_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: "ajaxforgotpassword",
                user_login: a("#user_login").val(),
                security: a("#forgotsecurity").val()
            },
            success: function(b) {
                a("p.errors", ctrl).text(b.message)
            }
        }), b.preventDefault(), !1)
    }), a("#register").length ? a("#register").validate({
        rules: {
            password2: {
                equalTo: "#signonpassword"
            }
        }
    }) : a("#login").length && a("#login").validate(), a("#forgot_pass").length && a("#forgot_pass").validate()
});
```

Comment: did this didn't work for you? https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys I added .addClass("burimi") and .removeClass("burimi") on two different lines the full code is below thanks for all help and responses:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(a) {
    a("#pop_login, #pop_signup").on("click", function(b) {
        jQuery('body').addClass('burimi');
        return formToFadeOut = a("#register"), formtoFadeIn = a("#login"), "pop_signup" == a(this).attr("id") && (formToFadeOut = a("#login"), formtoFadeIn = a("#register")), formToFadeOut.fadeOut(10, function() {
        formtoFadeIn.fadeIn()
        }), !1
    }), a("#pop_forgot").click(function() {
        return formToFadeOut = a("#login"), formtoFadeIn = a("#forgot_password"), formToFadeOut.fadeOut(10, function() {
            formtoFadeIn.fadeIn()
        }), !1
    }), a(document).on("click", ".modal-backdrop, span.close", function() {
        return a("#login, #register, #forgot_password").fadeOut(10, function() {
            a(".login_overlay").remove()
            a("body").removeClass("burimi")
        }), !1
    }), a("#show_login, #show_signup").on("click", function(b) {
        a("body").addClass("burimi").prepend('<div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 541px;"></div>'), "show_login" == a(this).attr("id") ? a("#login").fadeIn(10) : a("#register").fadeIn(10), b.preventDefault()
    }), a("#login_form, #registration_form").on("submit", function(b) {
        return !!a(this).valid() && (a("p.errors", this).show().text(ajax_auth_object.loadingmessage), action = "ajaxlogin", username = a("#login_form #username").val(), password = a("#login_form #password").val(), email = "", security = a("#login_form #security").val(), "registration_form" == a(this).attr("id") && (action = "ajaxregister", username = a("#signonname").val(), password = a("#signonpassword").val(), email = a("#email").val(), security = a("#signonsecurity").val()), ctrl = a(this), a.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: ajax_auth_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: action,
                username: username,
                password: password,
                email: email,
                security: security
            },
            success: function(b) {
                a("p.errors", ctrl).text(b.message), 1 == b.loggedin && (document.location.href = ajax_auth_object.redirecturl)
            }
        }), void b.preventDefault())
    }), a("#forgot_pass").on("submit", function(b) {
        return !!a(this).valid() && (a("p.errors", this).show().text(ajax_auth_object.loadingmessage), ctrl = a(this), a.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: ajax_auth_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: "ajaxforgotpassword",
                user_login: a("#user_login").val(),
                security: a("#forgotsecurity").val()
            },
            success: function(b) {
                a("p.errors", ctrl).text(b.message)
            }
        }), b.preventDefault(), !1)
    }), a("#register").length ? a("#register").validate({
        rules: {
            password2: {
                equalTo: "#signonpassword"
            }
        }
    }) : a("#login").length && a("#login").validate(), a("#forgot_pass").length && a("#forgot_pass").validate()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery notation: `$("body").addClass("someclass")`, if I understand correctly.

Comment: exactly but there are 3 modals in my javascript code and would be nice to add one code for all

Comment: @user5014677 is correct. If you have control over the modal creation, you can inject same class in all modals and access them by jQuery class selector.

Comment: thankyou I have resolved it but added also remove class because the body tag was remaining there also if the modal was closed.Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any button in your code but heres something that may help you:

```
//target tags with a class starting with "modal" i suppose your "modal" buttons have this class which i don't see in the code
$('[class^="modal"]').click(function(){
   //Add class to body
   $("body").addClass("myClass");
});
```

you can do like `$('input[class^="modal"]')` if your button is an input or change to div or what ever.

or just `$(".myModalButtonClass").click(...)`